# Error checking if username exists before register

Tags: c#, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

*** I worked out what was causing the errors, it was due to me calling error.message.text inside of the SignUpAsync,

I hope i get some help here, Been on this for 2 days for just a simple login..

I have register working, but if i use the same username again it wont work, however it wont return any errors or anything for me to work with and alert the user...

I am using this from the docs

```
//try and register user and catch any errors.
            try
            {
                Task signUpTask = user.SignUpAsync().ContinueWith(t => {
                    if (t.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        // Errors from Parse Cloud and network interactions
                        using (IEnumerator<System.Exception> enumerator = t.Exception.InnerExceptions.GetEnumerator())
                        {
                            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                            {
                                ParseException error = (ParseException)enumerator.Current;
                                ErrorMessage.text = error.Message;
                                Invoke("ClearForm", 4);

                                // error.Message will contain an error message
                                // error.Code will return "OtherCause"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ErrorMessage.color = Color.green;
                        ErrorMessage.text = "Login Success";
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                ErrorMessage.color = Color.red;

                ErrorMessage.text = e.Message;
                Invoke("ClearForm", 4);

                // Error from the SDK logic checks
                // e.Message will contain the specific error
                // ex: "Cannot sign up user with an empty name."
            }
```

Since i failed on this for 2 days, i decided to just make a function that checks the username each time the inputfield gets updated, but even that doesn't work... and they only have 1 tiny little example for how to query Users... It really needs some example docs.. please...

here is what i tried.

```
public void CheckUserName()
{
    if (UserNameInput.text.Length > 2)
    {

        ParseUser.Query.WhereEqualTo("username", UserNameInput.text).FindAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.Result.Any())
            {
                //it found someone make error symbol
                UserNameInputError.sprite = ErrorSprite;
                UserNameInputError.enabled = true;
                ErrorMessage.color = Color.red;
                ErrorMessage.text = "UserName Taken";

            }
            else
            {
                //it didnt? make success symbol
                UserNameInputError.sprite = SuccessSprite;
                UserNameInputError.enabled = true;
                ErrorMessage.color = Color.green;
                ErrorMessage.text = "UserName Availible";
            }

        });
    }
    else
    {

        UserNameInputError.sprite = ErrorSprite;
        UserNameInputError.enabled = true;
        ErrorMessage.color = Color.red;
        ErrorMessage.text = "Username Must be More Than 2 Characters";
    }

}
```

However this does not seem to work and i get no feedback from parse.. just 2 errors in console which might be related?

The errors are:

`get_isActiveAndEnabled can only be called from the main thread.
Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function.`

and

`set_enabled can only be called from the main thread.
Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function.`

I hope someone can help.. and please provide me an example on how to check the username exists?

How to Catch the login error in my signuptask above?

and how to store the email in the parseuser that i get from successful facebook login..

thanks so much..

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I was calling unity methods inside the async.. Realised I didn't need to as i can just detect if parseuser.currentuser is not null to print my success message.